# why the audio goes out of sync with video in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, hls.js

I have a website which shows some movies online. I'm using hls.js version 0.12.4 for streaming my videos and every thing works fine most of the time, but occasionally when our users use chrome, the movie's audio goes out of sync with the right frame of video and this asynchronism get worse and worse till refresh the browser. how can I fix this issue?
does anybody know that upgrading to last hls.js version solve the problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with the version of Chrome that you are using. Google has documented this problem happening with the embedded media player in Chrome(Google Chrome bug= 1018904, Chrome version 78.0.3904.90)